# Paypal Rest Api Internal Server Error on Create Agreement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using Paypal REST api to create subscription plan and subscription agreement. I am able to create subscription plan and credit card but not able to create agreement. Whenever I request it gives internal server error.

I am using ruby gem `paypal-sdk-rest`

Credit card I am using is

> 4012888888881881

And mode is `Sandbox`

the Response I am getting is

> Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error. 
>   Response debug ID = ea61a34e9fa73

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of frequently used test Credit Card like the one you are using, if you are use different one for this it will help you to solve this issue...

Or may be below one cause of the error
Sandbox Personal Account being used was invalid. The sandbox personal account is causing all this error 500.

Comment: But I am able to get credit card token with the same creditcard. 
And I have tried after 12 hr using the above  credit card but still  same result.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 is caused by an internal error. One of the possible root causes is what JIGNESH mentioned.
Can you please open a Github issue with the information you provided here? It is a better place to discuss this kind of issue.

Also, would you explain how you are using subscription? Ruby REST SDK does not yet support the feature, although it is coming soon. Did you add it yourself?

Comment: I have added classes necessary to make subscription work using paypal rest sdk.
And I made it work using 'paypal' method and not 'credit_card'.

Comment: We will release subscription API support soon. In the mean time, it will be great if you raise an issue on REST Ruby SDK github: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby